# removing last element in arraylist exception

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

At first there was an issue removing an element in an arraylist if it was the only one on the list but now there is an exception issue when deleting the last position of the arraylist. What is the best way to deal with this?

edit: Looking back, checking if it is the last element and putting in a dummy element to hold the only spot would work.

the code:

```
  public void deleteCustomer(){
            String id = null;
            boolean c = false; //true if id is found
            int remember = 0;      //Remembers the deleted index

            id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"input the if of whome you want to delete",
                    "input id", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

            int id2 = Integer.parseInt(id); //new int id.


            for(int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++){

                if(id2 == customers.get(i).getID()){

                    if(customers.size() == 1){
                        System.out.println("test one person");
                        customers.get(i).setDate(null);
                        customers.get(i).setID(0);
                        customers.get(i).setName(null);
                        customers.get(i).setPeople(0);
                    }
                    else{   
                     customers.remove(i);
                    }
                    c = true;
                    remember = i;

                if(c == true)
                break;
            }
            }

            if(c == true){

                int i1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"the customer "
                       + customers.get(remember).getName() + " has been deleted.",
                            "input people", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

            }
            else{

                int i1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"the customer could not be found," +
                        " please check your id",
                                "input people", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

            }



        }
```

> the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at MainFrame.deleteCustomer(MainFrame.java:360)
    at MainFrame$4.actionPerformed(MainFrame.java:170)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: `customers.get(remember).getName() + " has been deleted."` Erm. How to you expect it to be there when you've removed it?

Comment: If Size is 1 index should be 0, debug your code there is some logical issue...

Answer (score 2):

**Don't remove** elements from a collection while iterating over it with a for loop. Use an iterator instead which in most cases implements the `remove` method.

```
Iterator<Customer> it = customers.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
 if(it.next().getId() == id2) {
  it.remove();
 }
}
```

Comment: or if you must; traverse it backwards

Answer (score 1):

That's because you already removed one value, but the initial value in the condition (`customer.size()`) remains the same. So, the ACTUAL size of the list is 1, even though in the beginning was 2 or more.

What I would suggest is that instead of the for loop you use the iterator:

```
Iterator it = customers.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Customer customer= (Customer) it.next();
    //do stuff with the customer

    //remove the customer
    it.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a problem in your output.
After deleting the element with index i, you remember i.

```
   int i1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"the customer "
                   + customers.get(remember).getName() + " has been deleted.",
                        "input people", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

This piece of code, therefore, tries to access a deleted element from the list to get the name.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you rewrite your method with the suggestions given by all previous answers. Something like this:

```
public void deleteCustomer(){
        String id = null;
        int remember = 0;      //Remembers the deleted index

        id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"input the id of whome you want to delete",
                "input id", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        int id2 = Integer.parseInt(id); //new int id.

       Iterator<Customer> itr = customers.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            Customer thisCustomer = itr.next();
            if(id2 == thisCustomer.getID()){
                customers.remove(thisCustomer);
                break;

             }
             remember++;
        }

        if(remember < customers.size()){

            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"the customer has been deleted.",
                        "input people", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        }
        else{

            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"the customer could not be found," +
                    " please check your id",
                            "input people", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        }


}
```